# AWS Javascript SDK issues - deleteObject working but deleteObjects doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I'm getting myself familiar with the Javascript SDK for my S3 bucket, and I'm stuck on this CORS error which is rather perplexing.

My putObject and deleteObject function works just fine, I have my site use a public IAM user that has permissions to both delete and put objects in my bucket.

However, I am now moving onto the deleteObjects function (allowing me to delete multiple files with one request), and I'm getting this error:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I don't understand. If my IAM user has permission to delete and put, it shouldn't be giving me this CORS error, right?

Here's my deleteObjects function:

```
    AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: $scope.creds.access_key, secretAccessKey: $scope.creds.secret_key });
    AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket } });

    var params = {
        Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket,
        Delete: {
            Objects: [
                {
                    Key: "pic1"
                },
                {
                    Key: "pic2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    bucket.deleteObjects(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The deleteObject operation uses the DELETE http method, but deleteObjects uses the POST http method. You'll need to add:
    `<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>`
to your bucket's CORS configuration for deleteObjects to work.